# Light-like interval and simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, causality

Why if the interval between two events is light-like then there is no frame of reference where the events occur at either the same time? If I assume that the 2 events happen at the same time, I arrive by definition that they must happen at the same point in space. I tried to define an inertial observer that moves at a speed v, but by performing the Lorentz transforms I found that in that frame of reference the events are also simultaneous and occur at the same point. So I can't find or understand why the 2 events can't be simultaneous.

$\Delta S_{12}^{2}=0=c^{2}\Delta t^{2}-\Delta r^2$

If $\Delta t^{2}=0$ then $\Delta r^2=0$ then:
$\Delta t' = \gamma(\Delta t - v\Delta r /c^2)=0$ and $\Delta x' = \gamma(\Delta x - v\Delta t)=0$

Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Two points determine a line.  If that line is lightlike, it can't also be spacelike.

Answer (score 1):

If two points are lightlike separated, that means light can leave one and get to the other. That's why it's called lightlike separation: a hypothetical light ray could connect the points, so the distance between the points is "like" a light ray.

If two events are simultaneous but in different places, then of course light can't get from one to the other. Light has finite speed, but it would have to cover nonzero distance in zero time. So simultaneous, non-concurrent events can't be lightlike separated. Conversely, if you start with two simultaneous and lightlike separated events, you are forced to conclude they are the same event. (The proof of this statement is the calculation you're making!)

The light cone is actually invariant under Lorentz transformation. Events that are lightlike separated in one frame remain lightlike separated in all frames. So making a Lorentz transform won't get distinct lightlike separated points to be simultaneous, because simultaneous events are spacelike separated. (Also, it sounds like you tried to define an observer *with the same velocity as light?* That doesn't work: Lorentz transforms *don't exist* for $v\ge c.$)

Answer (score 0):

In relativity, an "[event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(relativity))" is a set of coordinates in Minkowski spacetime. If the assumption of simultaneity leads to their being at the same location, they are by definition the same event.

If you were looking for a "philosophical why" with this question, two events are simultaneous in some reference frame if they occur at the same time in that frame. This means that $\Delta t$ is zero in that frame. This means that the metric between them is spacelike (negative) because there must be a spatial coordinate that is different (or else it would not be two different events because the time coordinate is the same). This means that the interval is not lightlike (a lightlike interval has zero metric).